# Getting the status of email send or cancel in android

Tags: android, android-activity

Please check below mentioned code.
I used Java mail api also, but there is  a use of username and password.
Is there any another way to get the status of email send or cancel.
And please let me know the process of handling the status of email send or cancel in android.

```
Intent emailActivity = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);

// set up the recipient address
emailActivity.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[] { to });

// set up the email subject
emailActivity.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);

// you can specify cc addresses as well
// email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_CC, new String[]{ ...});
// email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_BCC, new String[]{ ... });

// set up the message body
emailActivity.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, message);

emailActivity.setType("message/rfc822");

startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(emailActivity,
                    "Select your Email Provider :"), 1000);
```

Comment: To solve this issue, I used Java mail. By using java mail, there is a need of username and password. These username and password are hot coded in activity or by getting edit text's data. If we are hot coded, only hot coded mail id getting mail. If we using edit texts, every time we are asking username and password is not good. Once we are login, there is no need to ask username and password. Other than these approach, there is any way to get the status of email send or cancel. Please help me anyone. ............Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The activity that initiates the sending of email using `startActivityForResult` should override `onActivityResult`:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
  super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

  // Check requestCode to know which request result you got back
  switch (requestCode) {
  case YOUR_REQUEST_ID:
    // Check the resultCode
    if(resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
      // The activity reported that everything went ok
    }
    break;
  // Check other results here
  }
}
```

Comment: Albeit this is a supposed way to go, I my case Gmail returns the very same result in all cases (sent, discarded, saved as draft,...):/